# regexp is not working as expected How to resolve?

Tags: jquery

As you can see regexp pattern I want at least 8 characters 1 special character, 1 lower and upper case letter. I fulfilled requirement but still returning false How to resolve?

```js
var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/;
alert(regex.test('11@99@99@66Shah'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Regex object as below:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/");
alert(regex.test('11@99@99@66Shah'));
```

If your regex is correct, then it will work fine :)

Comment: Bro, it still not working any alternative solution?

Comment: I don't know bro I got it from stackoverflow.